# EditTextPreference Password field

Tags: android

I am trying to include an `EditTextPreference` for a password, and want to hide the characters and show asterisks, but not able to do it.

this is my preference.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Scenes">
    <DropDownPreference
        android:key="scenario"
        android:title="Select scene"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:entries="@array/scenarios"
        android:entryValues="@array/scenarios_values" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Demo">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="connect_on_startup"
        android:title="Auto Connect"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summary="Connect automatically at startup" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="UserName"
        android:key="username"
        android:summary="Please provide your Username"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditTextPreference>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:title="Password"
        android:key="password"
        android:summary="Please provide your Password"
        android:password="true" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

What can I be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 1):

In Androidx this must be done with the following two step process

```
EditTextPreference passwordEditText = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("password");

        passwordEditText.setOnBindEditTextListener(new androidx.preference.EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }
        });
        passwordEditText.setSummaryProvider(new Preference.SummaryProvider() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence provideSummary(Preference preference) {
                int valueSize= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),"").length();
               String newSummary="";
                for (int i = 0; i < valueSize; i++) {
                  newSummary+="*";
                }
                return newSummary;
            }
        });
```

Comment: this is definitely the answer, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`android:password="true"` is deprecated you should use  `android:inputType="textPassword"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide text shown in the summary, it should be done outside of the xml file. You probably have code template from android studio that contains implementation of `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`. Inside of it there is callback method that is called when settings are changed. By default it changes summary to the incoming value:

```
preference.setSummary(stringValue);
```

Instead of it, you need to check if the preference is your password and skip setting the summary, something like this:

```
if ("password".equals(preference.getKey())) {
    preference.setSummary("***");
} else {
    preference.setSummary(stringValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in fact, I only want to hide the password when the user is typing it.